Firebase/Angular | Can't get firebase emulators to work
Trying to complete this tutorial: [https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web?hl=en#0]
I can do everything up until step 5, but when i start the emulators with command "firebase emulators:start" on step 6
i get an error and the emulators shut down:
i  emulators: Starting emulators: auth, functions, firestore, hosting
!  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: database, pubsub
+  functions: Using node@20 from host.
i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
+  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
+  hosting[friendlychat]: Local server: http://localhost:5005
i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log
!  ui: Fatal error occurred: 
   Emulator UI has exited with code: 1,
   stopping all running emulators
i  ui: Stopping Emulator UI
!  ui: Error stopping Emulator UI
i  functions: Stopping Functions Emulator
i  hosting: Stopping Hosting Emulator
i  firestore: Stopping Firestore Emulator
!  Firestore Emulator has exited upon receiving signal: SIGINT
i  auth: Stopping Authentication Emulator
i  hub: Stopping emulator hub
i  logging: Stopping Logging Emulator

ui-debug.log contents:
C:\Users\PsychoSpike\.cache\firebase\emulators\ui-v1.4.2\server.bundle.js:1
r t=n;if(a&&"object"==typeof a)for(var i,r=Object.keys(a).sort(),s=0;s<r.length;s++){if(i=r[s],!o.test(i))throw new TypeError("invalid parameter name");t+="; "+i+"="+p(a[i])}return t},a.parse=function(e){if(!e)throw new TypeError("argument string is required");var a="object"==typeof e?function(e){var a;"function"==typeof e.getHeader?a=e.getHeader("content-type"):"object"==typeof e.headers&&(a=e.headers&&e.headers["content-type"]);if("string"!=typeof a)throw new TypeError("content-type header is missing from object");return a}(e):e;if("string"!=typeof a)throw new TypeError("argument string is required to be a string");var n=a.indexOf(";"),i=-1!==n?a.substr(0,n).trim():a.trim();if(!c.test(i))throw new TypeError("invalid media type");var o=new l(i.toLowerCase());if(-1!==n){var s,p,u;for(t.lastIndex=n;p=t.exec(a);){if(p.index!==n)throw new TypeError("invalid parameter format");n+=p[0].length,s=p[1].toLowerCase(),'"'===(u=p[2])[0]&&(u=u.substr(1,u.length-2).replace(r,"$1")),o.parameters[s]=u}if(n!==a.length)throw new TypeError("invalid parameter format")}return o}},function(e,a,n){"use strict";e.exports=Object.setPrototypeOf||({__proto__:[]}instanceof Array?function(e,a){return e.__proto__=a,e}:function(e,a){for(var n in a)e.hasOwnProperty(n)||(e[n]=a[n]);return e})},function(e,a,n){"use strict";
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 't'
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:77:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49

Node.js v20.11.1

I have no idea what i am doing wrong. Is this a problem with the tutorial or (probably) with my limited knowledge?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I just tried to follow the tutorial to the letter.
-I had some difficulty on step 5:
"ng add @angular/fire" where selecting an email after selecting components would result in "Already using account for this project directory".
Downgrading firebase tools as suggested in this post(https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3121) let me finish this step and no longer give an error about the account.
-I had node v20 installed and the project asked for node 18. I changed it in the package.json file to use 20 and it no longer gives that error.
The problem still remains in step 6, trying to start the emulators gives same error.
